# Accessing image stored in iPad application's local sandbox with HTML<img> tag

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am trying to build an HTML-based application for the iPad. I want to access an image stored in the application's sandbox, i.e. the documents directory, using an HTML `<img`> tag. I am passing ~/Documents/image.png to src but the image is not getting displayed.

Answer (score -1):

Note that the directory will vary depending on whether you are in the Simulator or on a device, and should be determined at runtime.

If you would like something out of the main bundle to embed in html (like if you included it in Resources):

```
NSString* cssFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:cssFilePath];
NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blahblah... <img src='%@'> ...", fileURL];
```

Comment: Hmm not sure why this was downvoted. If it's wrong I'd appreciate it if someone could let me know why. :)